# TypeError Process.env not defined

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

Here is the problem i am trying to used vuelidate package in my nuxt3 website for validation

I have installed the package when i import it in file it says process.env error

```
npm install vuelidate --save
```

```
import { required, minLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
```

it says process.env is not defined

quick solution of it

Comment: Mind sharing more details? Like the version of vuelidate or maybe a repro of it?

Comment: sure its version is 0.7.7
i am using it in nuxt3 
node version is 18.16.0

Comment: "it says process.env error" - says who? What is the exact message? It could happen in different places and could mean different things. The question lacks clear problem statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .